# Merge XYZ Files: "ERROR 1: Attempt to create 6961x-8398 dataset is illegal, sizes must be larger than zero."

Tags: qgis, gdal, xyz

So I am trying to merge 200+ XYZ files to one Raster-layer. And i get the following Exception:

```
2022-05-01T14:18:23     INFO    gdal_merge.bat -n -398.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff -o C:/Users/magni/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_MxJKnH/7594b6e23eeb4b94acf98757b5f2f93a/OUTPUT.tif --optfile C:/Users/magni/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_MxJKnH/5137629ad1f8401cb8c9d6169b4e1b05/mergeInputFiles.txt
2022-05-01T14:18:25     INFO    GDAL execution console output
             ERROR 1: Attempt to create 1201x-398 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.
Creation failed, terminating gdal_merge.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am also interested in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, it seems that the **merge** algorithm does not work on XYZ files. On the other hand, it works perfectly on GeoTIFF files. Therefore, I suggest here to use the **Warp (reproject)** algorithm to convert the layer(s) from the XYZ file format to the GeoTIFF file format and then use the **merge** algorithm. For multiple files, you can use the batch mode for both algorithms.